# js loop after a certain json node

Tags: javascript, json

I'm trying to loop through some json nodes after finding a specific json node.

So, here's the INPUT:

```
{
"search": {
    "result": {
        "DN": {
            "$": "A,B,C"
        },
        "attribute-value": [
            {
                "@name": "name",
                "$": "nameHere"
            },
            {
                "@name": "account",
                "$": "accountNameHere"
            },
            {
                "@name": "role",
                "$": "roleA"
            },
            {
                "@name": "role",
                "$": "roleB"
            }
        ]
    }
}}
```

As you can see there are 2 roles at the end of the json payload above.
So, I get to that @name = role with the following logic:

```
var attributeValue = node['search'].result['attribute-value'];
for (var i = 0; i < attributeValue.length; i++) {
    if (attributeValue[i]['@name'] === 'role') {
        var vRole = attributeValue[i].$;

        //The newJson.roles.role is to assign it to the new payload below
        newJson.roles.role = vRole;
    }
}
```

Once I get there, I'd like to pick up both roleA and roleB and output it into the following newJson payload:

```
var newJson = {
    "newJson": {
        "roles": [{
            "role": {}
        }, {
            "role": {}
        }],
    }
}
```

The goal is to be able to get all the INPUT role nodes and output it in the newJson payload, but when I attempt to issue a for loop after getting to that @name=role, it fails.

Any suggestion is well appreciated.
Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
var attributeValue = node['search'].result['attribute-value'];
var newJson = {roles:[]};
attributeValue.forEach(function(item){
  if(item["@name"]==="role"){
    newJson.roles.push({role:item["$"]})
  }
});
console.log(JSON.stringify(newJson));
```

Answer (score 2):

I think you should append a new object to the roles array, just like this in your for loop:

```
var attributeValue = node['search'].result['attribute-value'];
for (var i = 0; i < attributeValue.length; i++) {
    if (attributeValue[i]['@name'] === 'role') {
        var vRole = attributeValue[i].$;

        newJson.roles.push({
            role: vRole
        });
    }
}
```

Hope this can help

Answer (score 0):

You can use `filter` and `map` array methods.

```
newJson.roles = attributeValue
  .filter(function(x){return x['@name']==='role'})
  .map(function(x){return {'role': x['$']}})
```

Answer (score 0):

Thanks everyone - you're all awesome!
This worked out for me:

[JSBIN](https://jsbin.com/gazalaciqa/edit?js,console)

```
var d = {
"search": {
    "result": {
        "DN": {
            "$": "A,B,C"
        },
        "attribute-value": [
            {
                "@name": "name",
                "$": "nameHere"
            },
            {
                "@name": "account",
                "$": "accountNameHere"
            },
            {
                "@name": "role",
                "$": "roleA"
            },
            {
                "@name": "role",
                "$": "roleB"
            }
        ]
    }
}};

var newJson = {
    "newJson": {
        "roles": []
    }
};


var attributeValue = d.search.result['attribute-value'];

for (var i = 0; i < attributeValue.length; i++) {
    if (attributeValue[i]['@name'] === 'role') {
        var vRole = attributeValue[i].$;

        newJson.newJson.roles.push({"role": vRole});
    }
}

console.log(newJson);
```

~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~~ final result ~~~~~~~~~~~~~~

```
[object Object] {
  newJson: [object Object] {
    roles: [[object Object] {
  role: "roleA"
}, [object Object] {
  role: "roleB"
}]
  }
}
```